# Twig trouble getting keys from 2 merged arrays

Tags: php, twig

I have 2 arrays carrying similar data, I only need data from the the key "testimonial_section" on each of them. 
 I know how to get the data from either of them (openGames[#].testimonial_section), but how would I best fetch the data from both?

```
string(31) "openGames.testimonial_section"
NULL

string(32) "openGames[0].testimonial_section"
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["testimonial"]=>
    string(32) "
"the kidnapping" Test 1 


"
    ["author"]=>
    string(13) "test author 1"
  }
}

string(32) "openGames[1].testimonial_section"
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["testimonial"]=>
    string(34) "
norcross kidnapping test 1


"
    ["author"]=>
    string(28) "norcross kidnapping author 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["testimonial"]=>
    string(34) "
norcross kidnapping test 2


"
    ["author"]=>
    string(28) "norcross kidnapping author 2"
  }
}
```

In the end I need a conditional based one either arrays having data, I'm trying to run something like...

```
{% if testimonial_section != empty %}
  {% for each_section in testimonial_section %}
  {{ each_section.testimonial }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I'm pretty new to twig and I'm having trouble filtering out how to do this through the docs. Hope you can help.

Comment: if more information would help just be specific

Comment: how does testimonial_detail relate to testimonial_section, maybe dump the twig variables and then say what you want from them {{ dump(var1)}} and {{dump(var2)}}

Comment: typo, testimonial_section not testomonial_detail

Comment: Typos are the most defeating mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
  {% for each_section in openGames %}
      {% if each_section.testimonial_section != empty %}  
         {% for each_testimonial in each_section %} 
           {{ each_testimonial.testimonial }}
         {% endfor %}
       {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
```